# Bogachev change of variables theorem.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am reading the Bogachev's change of variable theorem proof. And I am stuck in an argument contained in it:

Let $F:U\subset \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ an injective $C¹$ map. Given $\epsilon>$ there exist $\delta>0$ s.t  $\forall x,y \in U,~\|x-y\|<\delta$ implies 
$$
F(x)-F(y)=F^{'}(x)(y-x)+r(x,y)
$$
where $\|r(x,y)\|\leq \epsilon \|x-y\|$.

Here is where I am stucked:

**Claim:** Let $Q$ be a cube with center $x_0$ and diameter less than $\delta.$ If $|\det F'(x_0)|\leq \sqrt{\epsilon}$ then  we have that
$$
\lambda (L(Q))-\lambda(F(Q))\leq \sqrt{\epsilon}\lambda (Q)
$$ 
where $L(x)=F^{'}(x_0)(x-x_0)+F(x_0)$ and $\lambda$ is the $n$-dimensional lebesgue measure.

Can someone give me some help?

**Comment:** I think the argument pass over to give some inferior bound for 
$\text{diam}( F(U))$ by using in some way the inequality 
$\|F(x)-F(y)\|\geq \|F^{'}(x_0)(x-y)\|-\|r(x,y\|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know enough measure theory but since $\lambda(L(Q))=\det L \cdot \lambda(Q)$, you could try to prove that $\det L \le \frac{\lambda(F(Q))}{\lambda(Q)} + |\det F'(x_0)|$.

Comment: $L$ is not a linear transformation, it is linear + a shift. As such it doesn't have a determinant (at least in the standard sense).

Answer (score 0):

$\lambda(L(Q)) - \lambda(F(Q) \leq \lambda(L(Q)) = \lambda(F'(x_0)Q + (F(x_0) - F'(x_0)x_0)) = \lambda(F'(x_0)Q) = |\det F'(x_0)| \lambda(Q) \leq \sqrt{\epsilon}\lambda(Q).$

Where we use shift invariance as well as the scaling property under linear maps of Lebesgue measure, proofs of which can be seen in Folland, *Real Analysis*, Theorem 2.42 and 2.44 resp. [image]

[image]